# DB Restore from directory with pgAdmin

Tags: backup, database-backups, pgadmin

I want to restore/import a postgreSQL DB, that i have stored several months ago.

I stored the DB in directory and not in a *.backup file those days.

The directory has lots of files like xxxx.dat.gz, but i can't choose any option like 
"from directory" in PGAdmin.

So how can i restore this? isnt there any "restore from directory" option any more?

Comment: Very much depends on how you have made the backup, so try to remember that.

Comment: I made the Backup in PGAdmin by right click on database and store database to directory. Nothing else. I already restored it once several month ago the same way. But i miss the option "from directory" now.

Comment: pgAdmin version and OS? I have v1.18.1 on Win7-64 and the option's there.

Comment: i tested all available versions today including v1.18.1 and i have win7-64.

Comment: 'create db, rightclick on db, restore and from directory' is that correct? i do not have that option :(

Comment: Nothing like [this](http://imgur.com/rGqVCN9) or [this](http://imgur.com/2kQaOq1)?

Comment: this is exactly the option that i need. But i dont see it here. Only *.backup file possible :(